# streaming mean iou DeepLabv3+

Tags: tensorflow, deeplab

can someone explain me how streaming mean iou from works? I used the tensorflow research repository and their `eval.py` function runs everytime there is a new checkpoint. But which values does it take into account? The whole predictions since the beggining of the training process? Or it only computes the mIOU for the last checkpoint?

kind regards